# jquery detect keycode first press or second press

Tags: jquery

Is that possible to detect first press or second press ?  For example, like some of the video player, pressing the spacebar first time is pause and press again is playback. So I was curios is that possible to do that using jquery ?

```
if (e.keyCode == 32) { //space bar

}
```

Comment: You don't need to detect the number of times the key is pressed, instead on each press check the state of the video and change that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry I not understand

Comment: I'd use a counter. When you first click the specific keycode you increment a counter. But it depends on what you are doing. jQuery has many toggle functionalities that doesn't require you to do so.

Comment: @ImHappy I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to detect the number of times the key is pressed, instead on each press check the state of the video and change that. Assuming you're using HTML5 video, try this:

```
$('#myElement').keypress(function(e) {
    var video = $('#video')[0];
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (video.paused)
            video.play();
        else
            video.pause();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do that. You can make a boolean variable:

```
var hasFirstPress = false;
```

And then

```
if (e.keyCode == 32) { //space bar
    hasFirstPress = true;
}
```

Comment: How do you set it back to false? I think it is meant to be toggling between true and false.

Comment: Why would you want to reset it? When you refresh the page it will be false again

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag and check! Keep a testing area, for now I am using a `<textarea>`:

```js
$(function () {
  keyPresses = {};
  $("#test").keydown(function (e) {
    keyPresses[e.keyCode] = (keyPresses[e.keyCode] == undefined) ? 1 : keyPresses[e.keyCode] + 1;
    $(this).val($(this).val() + "Key pressed " + e.keyCode + " for " + keyPresses[e.keyCode] + " time.\n");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {font-family: Monaco, MonacoB, MonacoB2, Consolas; width: 90%; height: 500px; resize: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all suggestion , I got my own answer now.

```
var lastKeyPress = 0;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && lastKeyPress === 1) { // second times
        alert("pause");
        lastKeyPress = 0;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 32 && lastKeyPress === 0) { // first times
        alert("play");
        lastKeyPress = 1;
    }
});
```